# Structure assignment pattern must not use replication?

Tags: structure, replication, variable-assignment, system-verilog

There is a statement in Systemverilog LRM,

> Replication operators can be used to set the values for the exact number of members. The inner pair of braces in a replication is removed.
>
> ```
> struct {int X,Y,Z;} XYZ = '{3{1}};
> ```

When I try this code, compiler says

> Structure assignment pattern must not use replication

But, below style works well.

```
struct {int X,Y,Z;} XYZ = '{1,1,1};
```

Comment: it looks like a cadence issue. It works with vcs and aldec reviera.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I tried this exact syntax with the Cadence compiler (with SystemVerilog turned on) and it compiled successfully.

Comment: @Silicon1602 I tried 15.20 from EDA Playground. They could have fixed it since.

Comment: @Serge, yup, I tried 18.09. It seems to be fixed in that version.

Comment: @Silicon1602 Strange.. I am now also using cadence 18.09-006 xcelium version. still it shows a same compile error message.

Comment: @YunsungMo I am sorry! After your comment, I tried it again and now I also see the error. I must have switched from `'{3{1}}` to `{1,1,1}` before adding the `-sv` flag. My bad, sorry!

Comment: so, it looks like the cadence issue after all. I guess, they need to be told about it.